# Are my class diagrams Correct?

Tags: class-diagram

I've made two class diagrams. But I am not sure if they are correct or not. These classes were in the same package and I used *Visual Paradigm* for making the class diagrams. However, I couldn't make one `ReadOutputFileforBreastAndColonCancer` class for both `WeakSignalFilter` class and `StrongSignalFilterClass`.

Therefore, I had to make two different class diagrams. Is it correct? Can I do it. 
Help will be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You can post images on many sites out there.  Please do so and post a link here.  I am also not sure if this is off-topic.  Not my downvote !

Comment: I don't see a `StrongSignalFilter` class in your diagram. Exactly what relationship do you want with your classes? And what do you mean you "couldn't make one `ReadOutputFileforBreastAndColonCancer` class for both `WeakSignalFilter` and `StrongSignalFilter`"?

Comment: This is one class diagram. The other class diagram is exactly like this one. It has "strongSignalFilter " class except for "WeakSignalFilter".

Comment: So you want both `StrongSignalFilter` and `WeakSignalFilter` an aggregation of `ReadOutputFileforBreastAndColonCancer`. From your diagram I don't see why not. What exactly did you do and see?

Comment: In visual Paradigm I had to use a top to down approach. So basically I had to make "StrongSignalFilter" class first and "WeakSignalFilter" class. However, for these classes I couldn't make one "ReadOutputFileForBreastAndColonCancer". Do you get my point? So I had to make two different class diagrams. Is this OK?

Comment: I think I know your problem now. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to VP's support page, [Creating class diagrams](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/94/2576/7190_creatingclas.html). First create the `StrongSignalFilter` class, then click its **Aggregation -> Class** resource beside it and drag to empty space of the diagram to create the `ReadOutputFileforBreastAndColonCancer` class. Next create the `WeakSignalFilter` class. Finally the crucial step: click the **Aggregation -> Class** resource beside the `WeakSignalFilter` class, and drag to the `ReadOutputFileforBreastAndColonCancer` class. This is how to create an association between two existing classes. And of course you can also create the three classes first before creating the two aggregrations.